# Minimal Model Program for sub-lc pairs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, minimal-model-program

In many articles of the minimal model program the authors work with sub-lc pairs instead of lc-pairs. In other words, they consider non-necesarilly effective boundary divisors $B$.

Is it expected (conjectured) that any sequence of flips for sub-lc pairs terminates?

Is this known for 3-folds? If yes, what is the standard reference for this?

Comment: I doubt that. Assuming that, for simplicity, $X$ is smooth, then any divisor $D$ can be written as $K_X+H_1-H_2$ where $H_1, H_2$ are very ample divisors. This pair is of course a sub-lc pair. So your question is basically asking the termination of $D$-MMP for arbitraty divisor $D$ on $X$, which is definitely not true.

Comment: To elaborate slightly: take your favorite infinite sequence of flops (if you don't already have a favorite, the classic example is due to Kawamata, and you can find it exposited in Reid's "minimal models of canonical 3-folds": it's a threefold elliptically fibered over a surface, and you keep alternately flopping the two components of a reducible fiber).  It's likely that your sequence is an infinite sequence of $D$-flips for some suitable non-effective $D$, and so you can't expect termination.  $D$ can even be pseff and exhibit this sort of behavior (this is the case in the Kawamata example).